# Derivation of an interpolation function with multiple arguments

Tags: interpolation, calculus-and-analysis

I have the following interpolation function:

```
f[x_,a_,b_]:=70 s[a,b][[1,1,2]][x]
```

where `s[a,b]` is the solution of a differential equation.

```
s[a_, b_] := NDSolve[{
   H2[x] == Rx[x]^2 + G[x, a, b],
   H2[xmax ]== 1,
   H2'[xmax] == Ans[xmax, a, b],
   H2''[xmax] == DAns[xmax, a, b]},
  H2, {x, xmin, xmax}];
```

I get this:

[image: Interpolation]

Now I want to define the derivative of this function as:

```
fd[x_,a_,b_]:=Derivative[1,0,0][f]
```

But it doesn't know how to compute it. I have also tried with

```
fd[x_,a_,b_]:=Derivative[1,0,0][f][x,a,b]
```

but it also gives me errors.

Comment: What's your code for s?

Comment: I didn't write it because it is a bit messy. It's an NDSolve (and I don't know how to write it as a porper code line here): s1[om_,ok_,h_,f0_,f1_,f2_,f3_]:=NDSolve[{
H2[x]==(Rx[x]/ff1[x,f0,f1,f2,f3])*
(1/2*(-f[x,f0,f1,f2,f3]+R[x]*ff1[x,f0,f1,f2,f3]/Rx[x])-
3*H2[x]*(ff2[x,f0,f1,f2,f3]*Rx[x]-ff1[x,f0,f1,f2,f3]*R2x[x])/(Rx[x]^2)+
3*(om*Exp[-3*x]+or[h]*Exp[-4*x]+ok*Exp[-2*x]))/3,
H2[xmax1]==1,
H2'[xmax1]==DH2ans[xmax1,om,ok,h],
H2''[xmax1]==DDH2ans[xmax1,om,ok,h]},
(*H2[xmin]==H2ans[xmin,om,ok,h],
H2'[xmin]==DH2ans[xmin,om,ok,h],
H2''[xmin]==DDH2ans[xmin,om,ok,h]},*)
H2,{x,xmin1,xmax}];

Comment: @Maria. It's not messy if it can fit in one comment! Please edit your original post with this code. Comments are ephemeral by design, and so we like questions to be complete on their own. Alternatively, you can come up with a minimal example (one that is simpler than your actual problem that still shows the problem that you are having) and post that instead; this would actually be preferred.

Comment: Try this instead. Define `fd[x_, a_, b_] := D[70 s[a, b][1, 1, 2][y], y] /. y -> x`.

Comment: @march It works indeed. May I ask why? Thank you :)

Comment: It's all about order of evaluation. For instance, if you define `fd[x_, a_, b_] := D[70 s[a, b][1, 1, 2][x], x]`, then when you call `fd[1, 1, 1]`, the right-hand side gets evaluated to `D[70 s[1, 1][1, 1, 2][1], 1]`, then the insides get evaluated to a number, etc. Basically, you want the derivative with respect to a variable, and a number gets put in its place before it can take the derivative. This is why you put `y` there, take the derivative with respect to that symbol (which is undefined), and then replace `y` with `x` (which is now a number).

Comment: You could also simply define `fd[x_, a_, b_] := 70 Derivative[1][s[a, b][1, 1, 2]][x]` which can be typed as `70 s[a,b][1,1,2]'[x]`